# Can't marshal a structure from an unmanaged library to managed code in monotouch

Tags: ios, binding, xamarin.ios, static-libraries

I have the following structure that is defined in a header file for a library that a vendor has given to us.

```
  typedef struct {
    int iLen;
    int iType;
    int state;
    unsigned char data[1200];
  } TCardCmdRespond;
```

I have created a structure in C# that I think matches it.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct TCardCmdRespond
{
    public int iLen;
    public int iType;
    public int state;
    public byte[] data;
}
```

I have a few things to point out here.  I am not sure what an unsigned char array should map to.  I initially guessed that unsigned char should map to char but char in C# is Unicode so that doesn't seem like it would work.  I also tried mapping it to a byte.  I also don't know if the length 1200 will be significant to the marshaler and if so, how to designate it.

I have the following method in my monotouch app that takes the structure as a parameter.

```
    [Export("OnRecvData:")]
    public void OnRecvData(TCardCmdRespond respond)
    {
        ...
    }
```

The method is invoked by the library via a selector.  The method is invoked without a problem.  The problem arises when I look at the data contained in the structure.  The numbers are extremely high when I am expecting them to be in the range between 1-3 (comparable objective-c code shows the iType to be in this range).  I have tried using bit-converter to reverse the byte order in case it is an endianness problem that the marshaler didn't solve for me.  The numbers are still high so I think the problem goes beyond simple endianness.

Further problems arise when I try to pull the data out of the char array.  It isn't null but trying to access it in any way beyond a null check crashes the application with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)

My workaround solution is to write a wrapper for this in objective-c that breaks the structure apart into parameters instead.  Then create a library that wraps it up and bind that instead.  My objective-c skills are not so hot and that is a slow process however.

Is there a way that I can make this work without having to wrap this up in an objective-c library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C# definition is incorrect.

The C version includes an inline block of 1200 bytes for the array, while your C# version contains a pointer to an array (4 bytes).

You can look at this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6.aspx

Comment: @migueldeicaza Thanks for the reply.  That was a major oversight on my part.  I'll give that a try and see if that fixes it.  I would certainly expect it to fix the access problems.  Do you think that will also fix the incorrect integers?  In any case I am much closer to a solution, thanks for your help.